# Reduce execution time in two foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-mvc

```
//Get linked claim for children list from ClaimLink
foreach (var claim in processedClaims)
{
    if (claim.Children == null)
    {
        claim.Children = new List<Claim>();
    }
    var claimRelationList = newClaimLink.Where(k=> k.ClaimLinkId == claim.Id).ToList();
    if (claimRelationList.Any())
    {
        //Get the claim for all selected ClaimLink
        foreach (var claimLink in claimRelationList)
        {
            var newChildren = claims.Where(p => p.Id == claimLink.ClaimId).ToList();
            claim.Children = claim.Children != null && claim.Children.Any() ? newChildren.Concat(claim.Children) : newChildren;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to reduce the execution time in above two foreach loop. Is there have better way than this?

Comment: try using `for` instead of `foreach` as it is cheaper in performance

Comment: Switching to `for` from `foreach` is going to get you a few milliseconds at best, it's more of a micro-optimization than anything.

Comment: What is `newClaimLink`? If it's a database context (e.g. Entity Framework) I would suggest batch fetching your information instead of doing it in a loop individually.

Comment: Switching foreach to for and try to not use LINQ where you can swap it with your implementation code

Comment: @NSKBpro LINQ isn't always slower, I feel like it would be better to recommend that the OP uses some diagnostics and finds out for himself whether it is worth keeping the LINQ. LINQ adds a lot of readability and coding speed over normal implementations and is quite often the same speed of execution in my experiences. (Depends what you're using it for).

Comment: Agree but in this case i feel like using Where clause surplus here. And of course if LINQ is bad why would exist such a evil thing? :)

Comment: It's not about LINQ being slow, it's about the algorithm in code that has O(N³) complexity. To reduce it you can use `HashSet` or `Dictionary` collections that has O(1) lookups

Comment: What are the sizes of `processedClaims` and `newClaimLink`? Is `newClaimLink` maybe an `IQueryable` that reads the database? What is the execution time now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my best answer for above question.

```
 //Get linked claim for children list from ClaimLink
        foreach (var claim in processedClaims)
        {
            if (claim.Children == null)
            {
                claim.Children = new List<Claim>();
            }
            var claimRelationList = newClaimLink.Where(k=> k.ClaimLinkId == claim.Id).ToList();
            if (claimRelationList.Any())
            {
                //Get the claim for all selected ClaimLink
                var newChildren = claims.Where(o => claimRelationList.Select(p => p.ClaimId).Contains(o.Id));
                if (newChildren.Any())
                {
                    claim.Children = claim.Children != null && claim.Children.Any() ? newChildren.Concat(claim.Children) : newChildren;
                }
            }
        }
```

I resolved my problem with lambda expression for the inner foreach loop then I could have to reduce the execution time more than 250ms.

Thank you for the helping me

Answer (score 1):

Multiple options i see at first sight:

1. don't call `ToList()`, not necessary here unless you have some sort of query executing in the background, see comment of @Shelby115
2. `newClaimLink.Where(k=> k.ClaimLinkId == claim.Id)` could be replaced by a dictionary created beforehand like `newClaimLink.ToDictionary(k=> k.ClaimLinkId)`
3. same goes for `claims.Where(p => p.Id == claimLink.ClaimId)`

Comment: You don't know that `ToList` isn't necessary. If that's using LINQ to SQL it might be forcing the query execution in which case you'd want to make a different optimization instead of just not calling it at all. You'd still probably want to prefetch them though.

Comment: Well ToList is questionable but Any or Where sometimes can be very very slow, plus  inside 1 or 2 loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `if (claimRelationList.Any())` condition as the following `foreach` will not iterate over an empty list. 
You already know that `claim.Children` is not null within that for each because you initialized it above. So I would replace

`claim.Children = claim.Children != null && claim.Children.Any() ? newChildren.Concat(claim.Children) : newChildren;`

With

`claim.Children.AddRange (newChildren)`.

Comment: `Concat()` works with empty lists too so technically `&& claim.Children.Any()` is unnecessary, though I do not know how that actually affects performance.

Comment: @SebastianHofmann I meant in regards to causing the `Concat()` to trigger every time instead of only when there were children in `claim`.

Comment: Let me just check this

Comment: @Shelby115 in my test it takes about 10 ms longer to check with `Any()` in 100000 iterations than just to call `Concat()`